# How to multiply numbers on the same line in a text file with Python?

Tags: python, text-files

Sorry if this question is rather basic, I am still learning Python.

I am trying to make a program that iterates through each line in a text file, multiplies numbers of the same line together, and assigns the product of these numbers to a variable called product.

For example, if the first line of a text file reads "1 2 3" the program would get the product of these numbers (6) and assign it to a variable called product1, and it would continue to do this for each line in the file, assigning separate variables to the product of each line. My program would then output the product of each line.

My program so far:
'''
file = open("apples", "r")

```
for line in infile:

    num = str(line)

    num = num.split(' ')

    num = int(num)

    total += num

print(num)
```

'''

Num is just a placeholder variable.

Example of a text document:

1 2 3

3 2 5

2 2 2

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your program is almost correct, just minor improvements:

1. It's good to open the file with help of context manager: `with ...`
2. The `num = str(line)` is not necessary, `line` is already a string
3. You should skip empty lines
4. Compute the product of the line with help of another for-loop
5. Store the product into a list and then print it

Example:

```
all_products = []
with open('<your file.txt>', 'r') as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        numbers = [*map(int, line.split())]
        # skip empty lines:
        if not numbers:
            continue
        product = 1
        for n in numbers:
            product *= n
        all_products.append(product)

# print all products:
for line, product in enumerate(all_products, 1):
    print('Line: {} Product: {}'.format(line, product))
```

Prints:

```
Line: 1 Product: 6
Line: 2 Product: 30
Line: 3 Product: 8
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
from functools import reduce

file = open("apples", r)
products = {}
i = 1
for line in file:
    product = reduce((lambda x, y: x * y), str(line).split(' '))
    products['product{}'.format(i)] = product
    i += 1
print(products)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def prod(line):
    x=1
    for n in num:
        x = x * int(n)
    return x
product = []
for line in infile:
    num = line.split(' ')
    product.append(prod(num))
   
print(product)
```

i think this would serve your purpose

Comment: Thank you for your help!